# Troubles With Eclipse with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I am running Eclipse Juno and am getting these errors about no resource found. This is a short copy and paste of them I didn't think all of them were needed.

```
[2014-11-09 13:50:41 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Adam\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-11-09 13:50:41 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-11-09 13:50:41 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Adam\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'
[2014-11-09 13:50:41 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-11-09 13:50:41 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Adam\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-11-09 13:50:41 - appcompat_v7]
```

Also I believe I am getting the error on the R from

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

because of these errors from no resource found. I have deleted all files several times and started fresh installs of Eclipse. I have made sure everything was updated. I have also tried using several different java SDK.

I am really lost, is it that Eclipse really hates me or Windows 8.1 or both?

Comment: want to tell us what specific steps you are taking?  odds are slim that Eclipse hates you or that it doesn't work on a major OS that released several months ago

Comment: Steps towards fixing it or steps I have taken before these errors accrue?

Comment: steps to get the error you want help diagnosing

Comment: Sorry very new to Android development. But the steps I take when the errors appear is I just create a new android project. I go through the wizard of naming it and so on, I dont change anything except the name of the project. When it loads into the main_activity and the screen where it shows the layout that is when all the errors appear at the bottom of eclipse. When I try to run the application it says my code has errors. So I then go to mainactivty.java and that is where i see the error for the R on R.android.layout.